# Why in Chrome when appending input in mousedown handler, it gets focussed?

Tags: javascript

When input field is added to the document in mousedown event and positioned on top of the element being clicked, sometimes it get focused.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var targ = document.querySelector("#target");

targ.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  container.appendChild(input, targ);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container>* {
  position: absolute;
}

#target {
  margin: 10px;
}

.container>input {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="target">Click here!</div>
</div>
```

Here is a Pen: https://codepen.io/motz-art/pen/jgyYoY

Why does it happened? And why doesn't it happened always?

Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: You might want to call `e.stopPropagation();` , or the click might continue bubbling onto new control..

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` do not prevents this. On the other hand `e.preventDefault();` does. I don't think it's related to bubbling as click happens on `#target` element which is sibling (but not parent!) of added `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `mousemove` event focuses it when mouse pointer is over newly added input field. Notice that when you hold mouse button pushed but you don't move your mouse and release mouse button without any movement, the input is not focused. If you do not have such a steady hand try to click using touchpad in a laptop ;)

A solution would be to catch `click` or `mouseup` event instead of `mousedown`.

Comment: Thank for replay. But why `mousemove` with focuses the input? Is it a Chrome bug?

Comment: I don't think that focusing is described by any standard, therefore it can be browser-dependant and implemented in slightly different ways. I am not familar with those standards in 100% so I might be not correct.

Comment: Anyway seems strange, so it may be a bug. Especially that mousedown event starts before element even exists